# In ASP.NET MVC with EF, how can you allow the user to create more data without asking them to enter every column of the model into a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

To be specific, a database might have a field like username which stores the email of the user currently logged on. When the user creates a new item, I'd like to be able to automatically grab their username with a command like `User.Identity.GetUserName()`, and then enter it into the username field automatically without asking them to input it (but there might be other fields to input in a form). What's the best way to do this?

The Controller looks like this:

```
    //GET: Reservations/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Reservations/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Username,StartDate,EndDate,Destination,Department")] Reservation reservation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reservations.Add(reservation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(reservation);
    }
```

Comment: Don't do it on the form. That can be spoofed. Update the model with the information in the controller before saving changes. Assuming you are requiring authentication of some kind you'll have the information easily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the create action you can pass in a model that has been pre-populated with some basic information. This will pre-populate the form in the same way as reopening a previously filled form. You don't have to back it with a real entry in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your question is really just "How do I get information about the user?". To get at the currently logged in user data:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Then, if you want the username:

```
user.UserName
```

Now, technically, the username is one of the few properties that you should be able to get directly off the `User` object:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

So, really, you'd only need to query the user if you needed something additional: name, email, etc.